# How to get rid of Dir Error 52 Bad File Name?

Tags: excel, vba

Context: In the previous sub the user creates a folder and files whose names correspond to the chosen month.
E.g. if the user chooses "March" the folder will be named "03.2020 March" and all files within it like this: "03.2020 March France" "03.2020 March Germany" etc.

I want to loop through all those files to paste a filtered data set based on the chosen country. I used DIR with wildcard characters.

Problem: When trying the DIR statement I come up against this error ("bad file name or number").

I've tried to pull out only the folder name, also with wildcard characters. I got the folder name in the `Debug.Print`. I assume therefore that the problem lies within the file name.

In the watch window the full path string after the first loop equals:

> "C:\Users\A135604\Desktop\Projekt*March*Austria.xls*"

```
Sub CopyToFNOLCountrySheets()

Dim FilterRegion As Range
Dim country(1 To 10) As String
Dim i As Byte
Dim r As Byte
Dim reportmonth As String `March
Dim folderpath As String
Dim countryfile As String
Dim fullpath As String  
Dim filetoopen As String

reportmonth = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cockpit").Range("A16").Value
folderpath = "C:\Users\A135604\Desktop\Projekt\" & "*" & reportmonth

Set fnwb = Workbooks("FNOLDataSource")
Set fnws = fnwb.Worksheets("FNOLAllData")
Set FilterRegion = fnws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

For i = 1 To 10
    country(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cockpit").Cells(i + 17, 1)
    countryfile = "\*" & country(i) & ".xls*"
    fullpath = folderpath & countryfile
    filetoopen= Dir(fullpath, vbDirectory)
    Debug.Print filetoopen
Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like that

```
folderpath = "C:\Users\A135604\Desktop\Projekt\" & "*" & reportmonth
folderpath = Dir(folderpath,vbDirectory)
folderpath = "C:\Users\A135604\Desktop\Projekt\" & folderpath
```

This will give you the correct directory name in this step.

In the loop you need to change the line for the `filetoopen`

```
filetoopen = Dir(fullpath, vbNormal)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what it changes. The problem appears only when I try to add the file name with wild characters. When I use DIR(folderpath) it prints the correct name of the folder "03.2020 March". Could you please explain a bit more + where to put your code exactly? Thank you

Comment: Ok, got it. Many thanks! Btw. would you like to share why it's working this way? Does it have sth to do with wild characters in the folder name? Or is it sth else?

Comment: The issue is that you wanted to combine two wild card searchs in one step for different objects. With the first wild card you look for a directory and with the second you look for a file. You can't do that in one line. You have to split these operations.